# Passing -ddump-splices to Stack script interpreter

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I'm using Stack interpreter feature and having a code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-9.0
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package yesod
     --package yesod-core
-}


{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
-- and the code goes on
```

I want to pass the `ddump-splices` option to the stack interpreter to it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `--` before passing the actual ghc option. i.e:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-9.0
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package yesod
     --package yesod-core
     -- -ddump-splices
-}
```

You can use `ghc --show-options` to see the kind of options you can pass. For more information, see here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/650#issuecomment-123470879